# PCB design of board based on ESP32 Pico

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, esp32

I have designed a simple board based on ESP32 Pico V3. Previously, I got a lot of help from this community with circuit and PCB design. Following the suggestions on my last question, I updated my schematics and converted it to a PCB design.

I asked a question about another PCB design previously and I tried to apply all the suggestions that I received on that question.

**This is my current work: https://oshwlab.com/youcanreplylishup/lime-choco**

[image]

[image]

Are there possible improvements on the design?

Comment: Never use the autorouter! That board is easy to route by hand and you'll get a much nicer result. The bottom layer is broken in too many places. Again, by hand routing you can fix most of this. Thicker tracks for the power. The RF routing has no hope of working. Spend some time putting the identifiers the right way up. Little things make a big difference.

Comment: @Kartman Thanks! Why won't the RF routing work? I found that 0.25mm track is alright for up to 1amp(https://resources.altium.com/p/pcb-trace-width-vs-current-table-high-voltage-design) and the board will use less than that. So, I guess the track width should be fine? And... do you mean the bottom copper layer is broken?

Comment: 2.4GHz RF is very critical. Those tracks are inductors and capacitors at that frequency. You need to use a coplanar waveguide. You don’t know what that is? Google! Track width for power might be ok for DC, no good for esp32. Choice of capacitors is incorrect - observe dc bias derating. Bottom layer is broken - just look at it! It is all chopped up. Should be continuous copper where possible. You really should make it easy for yourself and use a esp32 module rather than a chip - avoids a whole lot of problems.

Comment: @Kartman got it, I will try to fix the problems. Thanks!

Comment: @Kartman can you please provide me some useful and to the point article about doing coplaner waveguide? I have read about it and got the concept but can't understand how to correctly do it in pcb. Is it basically thick track with ground copper layer on each side and ground vias?

Comment: There are online calculators for  coplanar waveguide construction.  Have you read the esp32 hardware design guidelines document?

Comment: @Kartman I mean how to actually do it in pcb design tools?

Comment: And, if I use ceramic chip antenna, do i still need to do that?

Comment: The calculator tells you the track width and spacing required - lay down the tracks with that width and spacing. Place vias manually. There’s no magic. Why would you think the ceramic antenna would change the laws of physics? There’s many things you need to do. It was not a good choice to cut your teeth on a very critical pcb design.

Comment: Because the ceramic chip contains the antenna already, so i don't need trace antenna manually done, i guess. I only need the part from antenna to chip

Comment: Don’t guess. The coplanar waveguide is not an antenna. I’d suggest you look at other examples of pcb designs that use the esp32 chip. Just use a module - much better chance of success.

Comment: I think, I have misunderstanding and confusion in coplaner waveguide. Need to learn more